# Why does the action have to be hermitian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, action, unitarity, s-matrix-theory

The hermiticity of operators of observables, e.g. the Hamiltonian, in QM is usually justified by saying that the eigenvalues must be real valued.

I know that the Lagrangian is just a Legendre transformation of the Hamiltonian and so is also hermitian.

I am wondering if there is some other reason that the Lagrangian must be hermitian in QFT, this also made me question, why is it necessary that the action be real? am I missing some other underlying principle here?

Comment: Reading Weinberg's QFT V1, he states that having a non-real action for N complex-fields would result in 2N field equations, which cannot be satisfied except in some unique situations... This is a reasonably satisfying response, but I'll leave this question up to see if anyone else has anything to add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The classical action (of particles or fields) has to be real, because this means a real classical Lagrangian.
This is needed because (canonical) momenta are obtained (for instance for a particle) from the Lagrangian by $p_i = \frac{\partial \mathcal {L}}{\partial \dot x^i}$ , and momenta are real.

In QM or QFT, the action has to be understood as a phase, more precisely the probability amplitude to an history $H$ to happen is (in $\hbar  = 1$ units) :

$\psi_H = e^{iS_H}$

where $S_H$ is the classical action of the history $H$.

To have the total quantum probability amplitude, you have to sum over all possible histories :

$\psi = \int [DH]\psi_H = \int [Dh]e^{iS_H}$

So, the action does not correspond to a measurable quantity, it is a unobservable phase, it is not an observable.

If the action was an observable, you should be able to select a particular history among all histories, in some sense, extract a specific classical behaviour from a quantum behaviour, which is not possible.

Comment: Dear @Trimok How does it answer the question *why the Lagrangian/action  has to be real*?

Answer (score 4):

In quantum theory, the [S-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix) is [unitary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_%28physics%29) in order to preserve the concept of probabilities adding up to 100%. Unitarity is implemented via an appropriate [reality constraint/condition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16719/2451). E.g. in the [path integral formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) $$Z~=~ \int {\cal D}\phi~e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S},$$ the action $S$ should be real-valued.